# Why does Node.js on http-server freeze when you enter url parameter

Tags: html, node.js

I'm setting up a node.js server, and want to fix problem with freezing loading using http-server lib.

I've tried doing other URL parameter methods but it doesn't work and doesn't show any errors on console.

```
var url = require('url');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
if (req.url == '/watch') { 
if (!queryData.id) { res.write("Missing watch id?"); res.end(); }
res.end();
fs.readFile('player.html', function (err, html) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
res.write(html + "<div id='b6'>" + queryData.id + "</div>");
res.end();
});
}
});
```

I expect the output to get URL parameter and show the player.html.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one issue, but as-written, you have an errant `res.end()`, before you read in your `player.html` and return it to the response. Remove that line and see if it behaves as you expect.

Comment: I have removed the line and i have the same result, endless loading.